# android how to change toolbar title,image and background color in fragments

Tags: java, android

This is fragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<RelativeLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/topbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/black"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/bookappointment"
                        android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_medium"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_20sdp"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/dameklipCard"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_180sdp"
                    android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/topbar"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_15sdp">
                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:cardBackgroundColor="#f5f5ef"
                        card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
                        app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_15sdp">

                        <RelativeLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">
                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:id="@+id/rounderblue"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/_120sdp">

                                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/cardImg"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:background="@drawable/card_bg"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/services"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
                                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                                    android:textStyle="italic"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
                                    android:textColor="#EAEAEA"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
                                    android:text="@string/services"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/serviceTv"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/services"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/_25sdp"
                                    android:textColor="#EAEAEA"
                                    android:text=""/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/durationTv"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/serviceTv"
                                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
                                    android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_genraltext"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
                                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                                    android:text=""/>

                                <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/stylistImg"
                                    android:layout_width="@dimen/_74sdp"
                                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_74sdp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_16sdp"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_30sdp"
                                    android:src="#90eeeded"
                                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                    />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/stylistNameTv"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_below="@+id/stylistImg"
                                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/_11sdp"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_40sdp"
                                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                                    android:textStyle="bold"
                                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_10sdp"
                                    android:text="" />

                            </RelativeLayout>

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/timeTV"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/rounderblue"
                                android:fontFamily="@string/roboto_light"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"
                                android:textColor="#383838"
                                android:text="@string/your_appointment_date_time"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_15sdp"
                                android:textStyle="italic" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/dateTv"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/timeTV"
                                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                                android:text=""
                                android:textColor="#000000"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/_18sdp"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_16sdp"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>

                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/stylistRecycler"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_20sdp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/dameklipCard"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>


        </ScrollView>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

here is my fragment

```
public class StylistFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    String docid;
    CircleImageView stylistImg;



    public StylistFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.stylist_recycler, container, false);
        recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.stylistRecycler);
        stylistImg=view.findViewById(R.id.stylistImg);

        Bundle bundle=getArguments();
        if(bundle!=null){
            final String id=bundle.getString("userdocumentid","");
            docid=id;
            Log.d("selectedDocumentId",id);
        }
        try{
            FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
            try {
                db.collection("stylist").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    try {
                                        ArrayList<String> stylistId=new ArrayList<>();
                                        for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot:task.getResult()){
                                            String id=documentSnapshot.getId();
                                            stylistId.add(id);
                                        }
                                        StylistAdapter listAdapter = new StylistAdapter(task,docid,stylistId,stylistImg);
                                        RecyclerView.ItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecorator(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getContext(), R.drawable.divider));
                                        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
                                        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                                        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                                        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                    }catch (Exception e){
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

I am having five fragments in my project when i am selecteing the bottom navigation item it redirects to the corresponding fragment.But the issue is when i change the fragment the toolbar is getting refresh.I want to change only the title,image and background color of toolbar.I dont wan't to change the toolbar it should be same only i want to change title,image,background color.

Comment: share your java file

Comment: use `getActivity().setTitle("title");` fro image and background you can use `getActivity().setActionBar(Toolbar);`

Comment: if i want the title in center of the toolbar means what i have to do

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code may be help you

```
ColorDrawable mColorDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(mColorDrawable);
getActivity().getActionBar().setTitle("Alert");
```

**Or else**

Please use toolbar and set custom layout how you want like bellow is the example

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarM"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorDarkBlue"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rlTopBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolBarTitle"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="Text Title"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/font_very_large"
                     />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In Activity

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbarM);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: yeah i can set background color.the issue is i want to set title in center of the toolbar

Comment: Then I suggest else of action bar please use Toolbar in your layout.

Comment: k i will try with toolbar